# Cannot connect to SQL Server via WAN

Tags: sql-server

I've tried to connect to an SQL Server via WAN using as servername my WAN IP (in my case, a domain) but I can't do that when I can via LAN.

How can I fix that?

Comment: SQL Server needs certain ports to be open/accessible - e.g. port 1433 using TCP/IP protocol. Check your firewalls - are those ports open??

Comment: These ports are opened because I can connect that via INTRANET

Comment: So they're open internally, within your intranet - but are they open **to the outside world** ? I.e. are they open on your company firewall to the internet??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more specific?
How are you connecting to the server? Which language are you using? Can you paste the IP of both machines?

I'm not sure if you are using the right IP, but one thing to remember in networking is that "your own network does not know itself"; what I mean is that, supposing I have 64.148.129.89 as public IP, if I try to connect to that IP from any computer on my network, I will get the "Not Found Error" or a "Timeout Error."
Why? Well, simply because DNS doesn't make a U turn: After it bubles up outside of your network, it won't point back to the same spot.

What's the solution you say?
Use your local intranet IP to connect between machines. An example of intranet IP is 192.168.2.1 which usually points to your default gateway.

Comment: Then, I can't connect to a SQL Server from Internet, only from intranet ¿true?

Comment: yes, if you want to connect from outside your network to the inside, you will need to do a Port Forwarding from your router to one of your machines. Basically your router is the gate to your network, and what that does it tells your router to let any traffic at a specific port on it, go to a particular machine, so that way you can open up a port for SQL and get it redirected to the SQL server on your network
What you will need to do is find out which port is used by your sql server and then go to 192.168.2.1 and find "Port Forwarding"
if you want more details tell me which router your have

Comment: Hello, I've done a Port Forwarding indicating the server's LAN IP and the SQL Server port (1433) and I could solve my problem.

Comment: great im glad i could help you out :)